# Term count by user

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I am developing a section on the front of our website. Our users submit properties to our directory. we would like to show how many properties they have listed and what types. I have got this code but it shows all post counts by all users I just want to show their post count so it would be like Residential Properties: 15. This is the code I am using can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong.

```
$term = get_term( 110, 'property_type' );
// WP_Term_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => array( 'property_type' ),
    'name'       => array( 'Residential' ),
    'slug'       => array( 'residential' ),
    'author'     => $userID,
    'pad_counts' => false,
    'fields'     => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => true,
);

// The Term Query
$term_query = new WP_Term_Query( $args );
echo 'Residential Properties: '. $term->count;
```

Comment: Is `property` a custom post type? If so, you need to do a query for *posts* rather than *terms*. Terms just gets all terms that match your criteria - not posts within the terms.

Comment: I changed $term = get_post( 110, 'property_type' ); but now it just shows a blank space

Comment: OK, so what exactly are you trying to display? Should it show posts authored by given user from given term? What is that WP_Term_Query for?

Comment: Our aim is to the user how many properties they have in a category so we have a tax = property_type category name in tax = residential or postid 110, as we only want to show the user's posts count. This is what I am stuck on I can see how many posts/properties there is but for everyone I only want to show users posts/properties. Hope this helps. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit hard to guess, what are you trying to do exactly, but let me try to answer...

My best guess is that you want to tell, how many properties has given user published in given property type.

### So first - why your code doesn't work...

`get_term` will get the term info and there is no user context in it, so it will get count of all posts published in this term... So this won't help you.

`WP_Term_Query` is almost the same function. And, if you'll take a look at [its reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/), then you'll notice, that there is no `author` param. So it also won't help you.

**Why is it so?**

Because these functions are getting terms info and terms don't have authors...

### So how to get the count of posts in given term authored by given user?

The easiest ways will be to use WP_Query and use its `found_posts` field (which stores the total number of posts found matching the current query parameters)...

```
$posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => 'property',  // I'm guessing that is your post type
    'tax_query' => array(  // here goes your taxonomy query
        array( 'taxonomy' => 'property_type', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => 'residential' ),
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids', // we don't need content of posts
    'posts_per_page' => 1, // We don't need to get these posts 
) );

echo 'Residential Properties: '. $posts->found_posts;
```

Comment: wow what a perfect answer, makes sense, thank you for the perfect support Krzysiek Dróżdż, tested and works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but is there a way of showing how many properties / posts a user has that are published. I found the following but its now for tax. '<?php
// All pages
$total = wp_count_posts()->publish;
echo 'Total Posts: ' . $total;

// Pages with a category
$categories = get_categories('');
foreach($categories as $category) {
 $total += $category->count;
}
echo 'Total Posts: ' . $total;
?>'

Comment: @DirectWeb in all categories? Just remove tax query part from the code from my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Good call Krzysiek Dróżdż, as a ref i would like to share this code as someone may require any of this.

` $userID,
                                        'post_type' => 'listings', 
                                        'post_status' => 'published',
                                        'fields' => 'ids',
                                        'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                    ) );

```
                                echo 'Published Properties: '. $posts->found_posts;
                                ?>`
```